# System Call Interception (Hijacking) with Linux Loadable Kernel Module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to hijack a system call with loadable kernel module in Linux Kernel v4.19.8.

I could find the virtual address of `sys_call_table` from */boot/System.map-4.19.8*. However, when I tries to access to it, dmesg gives me the message below:

```
BUG : unable to handle kernel paging request at [address of sys_call_table]
```

So, here's my question.

1. Is it even possible to hijack system call with loadable kernel module in Linux Kernel v4.19.8?
2. If it is possible, how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I remember, syscall table is write-protected. You need to disable that protection when modifying the table. There are a lot of examples in the net about that.

Answer (score 1):

There are hooks you can use depending on the system call you're interested in. Often there's a callback that you can patch in with your module. So you might create a wrapper function and do some stuff then call the 'real' callback when you're done.

Check out this library:
https://github.com/pmem/syscall_intercept